# Is there a way for the cache to stay up without timeout after crash in AppFabric Cache?

Tags: appfabric

First my setup that is used for testing purpose:

- 3 Virtual Machines running with the following configuration:

  - MS Windows 2008 Server Standard Edition
  - Latest version of AppFabric Cache
  - Each one has a local network share where the config file is stored (I have added all the machines in each config)
  - The cache is distributed but **not** high availibility (we don't have Enterprise version of Windows)
  - Each host is configured as lead, so according to the documentation at least one host should be allowed to crash.
  - Each machine has the website I testing installed, and local cache configured
- One linux machine that is used as a proxy (varnish is used) to distribute the traffic for testing purpose.

That's the setup and now on to the problem. The scenario I am testing is simulating one of the servers crashing and then bring it back in the cluster. I have problem both with the server crashing and bringing it back up. Steps I am using to test it:

- Direct the traffic with Varnish on the linux machine to one server only.
- Log in to make sure there is something in the cache.
- Unplug the network cable for one of the other servers (simulates that server crashing)

Now I get a cache timeout and I get a service error. I want the application to still be up on the servers that didn't crash, and it take some time for the cache to come back up on the remaining servers. Is that how it should be? Plugging the network cable back in and starting the host cause a similar problem.

So my question is if I have missed something? What I would like to see happen is that if one server crashes the cache should still remaing upp since a majority of the leads are still up, and starting the crashed server again should bring it back gracefully into the cluster without any causing any problems on the other hosts. But that might no be how it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran through a similar test scenario a few months ago where I had a test client generating load on a 3 lead-server cluster with a variety of Puts, Gets, and Removes. I rebooted one of the servers multiple times while the load test was running and the cache stayed online. If I remember correctly, there were a limited number errors as that server rebooted, but overall the cache appeared to remain healthy.

I'm not sure why you're not seeing similar results, but I would try removing the Varnish proxy from your test and see if that helps.

Comment: I think it was working, but maybe the issue was me not having enterprise server version.